# Can you find the pattern?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

If the following are true:

> $4+7+2 = 281435$
>
> $7+3+9 = 212781$
>
> $6+2+7 = 121456$
>
> $2+8+5 = 164036$

Then what would the following equal?

> $8+4+6\ =\ ?$

Can anybody check my work? I think the answer is:

> $8+4+6 = 32 24 72$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algorithm is -

> First 2 digits = Product of 1st and 2nd digits
>  Next 2 digits = Product of 2nd and 3rd digits
>  Next digit = Take first digit and add 1 if its prime else subtract 1.
>  Last digit =   Product of 3 numbers. If first digit is odd, keep it as it is else subtract 2.

$4+7+2 = 281435$

> $4*7 = 27$
>  $7*2 = 14$
>  $4-1=3$
>  $4*7*2 = 56 = 5$    (First digit 5 is odd so keep it as it is)

$7+3+9 = 212781$

> $7*3 = 21$
>  $3*9 = 27$
>  $7+1 = 8$
>  $7*3*9 = 189 = 1$ (First digit 1 is odd so keep it as it is)

$6+2+7 = 121456$

> $6*2 = 12$
>  $2*7 = 14$
>  $6-1 = 5$
>  $6*2*7 = 84 = 8 - 2 = 6$ (First digit 8 is even so subtract 2)

$2+8+5 = 164036$

> $2*8 = 16$
>  $8*5 = 40$
>  $2+1 = 3$
>  $2*8*5 = 80 = 8 - 2 = 6$ (First digit 8 is even so subtract 2)

$8+4+6=?$

> $8*4 = 32$
>  $4*6 = 24$
>  $8-1 = 7$
>  $8*4*6 = 192 = 1$ (First digit 1 is odd so keep it as it is)
>  $322471$